# error in accessing surrounding variable in lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, function-call-operator

```
...
        unordered_map<string ,int> map;
        for (const auto& str : words) {
            map[str]++;
        }
        auto cmp = [map](string s1, string s2){
            if (map[s1] == map[s2])
                return s1 < s2;
            return map[s1] > map[s2];
        };
...
```

This give me `no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const unordered_map<std::__cxx11::string, int>' (aka 'const unordered_map<basic_string<char>, int>')`

But if I don't use [] operator but rather use .at() for access. The code compiles.

I don't know why. I check out [] operator and .at() :  both have the same method signature.

Comment: It is not good idea to do 4 lookups instead of 2, it is quite efficient on unordered map, but still. And you probably want to pass those strings as const reference instead of copying them on each comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables captured in a lambda are `const` by default, unless you mark the lambda as `mutable`. `unordered_map` does not have an `operator[]` that can be called on a `const unordered_map` object, since it inserts (ie *modifies*) a new element if the requested key is not found.

Also, you are capturing `map` *by value*, you should capture it *by reference* instead (unless you are expecting `cmp` to outlive `map`).

Try this:

```
unordered_map<string, int> word_counts;

for (const auto& str : words) {
    word_counts[str]++;
}

auto cmp = [&word_counts](const string &word1, const string &word2){
    auto iter = word_counts.find(word1);
    int count1 = (iter != word_counts.end()) ? iter->second : 0;
    iter = word_counts.find(word2);
    int count2 = (iter != word_counts.end()) ? iter->second : 0;
    /* or, throw an exception if word1 or word2 are not found...
    int count1 = word_counts.at(word1);
    int count2 = word_counts.at(word2);
    */
    if (count1 == count2)
        return word1 < word2;
    return count1 > count2; // <-- why > and not < ?
};
```

Answer (score 3):

> I check out [] operator and .at() : both have the same method signature.

No. [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) can't be called on `const` `map`. It might modify the `map` (if specified key doesn't exist). (BTW [`std::map::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) won't modify the `map`, it would throw `std::out_of_range` if the specified key doesn't exist.)

You can mark the lambda with `mutable`; otherwise the `operator()` of the lambda is const-qualfied and the captured object by copy is `const` too, then you can't call `operator[]` on it.

> **mutable**: allows body to modify the objects captured by copy, and to
>   call their non-const member functions
>
> Unless the keyword mutable was used in the lambda-expression, the
>   function-call operator is const-qualified and the objects that were
>   captured by copy are non-modifiable from inside this `operator()`.

e.g.

```
auto cmp = [map](string s1, string s2) mutable {
    if (map[s1] == map[s2])
        return s1 < s2;
    return map[s1] > map[s2];
};
```

---

PS: Not using name `map` for variable would be a good idea.